# CouchDB error using startkey&endkey in a key array

Tags: javascript, view, couchdb

Hi guys I'm trying to use the following request:

> curl  http://localhost:5984/contacts/_design/country/_view/USA?startkey=["USA",{}]&endkey=["USA",{}].

**On the following view:**

```
{
"_id": "_design/country",
"_rev": "1-51488ea3931fdca9b9e2de84ef99c4d9",
"language": "javascript",
"views": {
   "USA": {
       "map": "function(doc) {\nif(doc.type == \"contact\") \nemit([doc.country,doc.name] , {name: doc.name, email: doc.email});\n}\n"
   }
 }
 }
```

and I get this error: [globbing] bad range in column 72

Can you help me?

Comment: You should only include the `,{}` for `endkey`, leave it out of the `startkey`. In addition, I would wrap your URL in single quotes so your shell won't try and expand the `{}` as a glob pattern. (or try Alexis' answer about adding `-g`)

Comment: What does `startkey=["USA",{}]` do as opposed to `startkey="USA"` ?

Comment: i left the ,{} out of the startkey but i get the same error. if i use  startkey="USA" i get {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is coming from cUrl I suppose ? Try this :

```
-g/--globoff
              This  option  switches  off  the "URL globbing parser". When you set this option, you can
              specify URLs that contain the letters {}[] without having them being interpreted by  curl
              itself.  Note  that  these  letters  are not normal legal URL contents but they should be
              encoded according to the URI standard.
```

Comment: have you try Dominic Barnes comment?

Comment: yes i did. what about using something like startkey=%22USA%22?endkey... ?

Answer (score 0):

Just encode the brackets so that curl doesn't complain.
And you would probably want to use a different startkey (without the curly brackets), otherwise you won't get any results. The correct line:

```
curl http://localhost:5984/contacts/_design/country/_view/USA?startkey=%5B"USA"%5D&endkey=%5B"USA",%7B%7D%5D
```